# Has LinearLayout been replace with ConstrainedLayout?

Tags: xml, android-studio

[EDIT: if LinearLayout is still ok, then what do I need in the 'dependencies' instead of `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'`, because I cannot find a LinearLayout equivalent?]

I have recently updated to BumbleBee Android Studio. My old code used LinearLayout.

I just want a WebView where the WebView is forced to cover the full width and height of the screen with an advert at the bottom.

Its saying I need ConstrainedLayout now, but I am unsure how to do this? Or can I still use LinearLayout, but why is WebView red underlined. My old code was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFF" />

    <!-- Sizes BANNER, SMART_BANNER, LARGE_BANNER -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does it build?  Then you're probably good.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No it does not build. I have edited the question at the top to say why. Sorry I left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout) is not deprecated, unlike RelativeLayout.  So, it still has it's place.

This question is a bit broad in that opinions on how flat your View hierarchy should be come into place.  However, in complex hierarchy's, ConstraintLayout is the best option.

Edit:  Eh, w/e -- something close to this if you're using LinearLayout which implies no overlap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.support.package.here.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- Sizes BANNER, SMART_BANNER, LARGE_BANNER -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/webView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</your.support.package.here.ConstraintLayout>
```

I freeform typed that, so use it as guidance not the final solution hehe ;P.  I'd advise [reading up on the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), and tryin' a few views and it'll come together for you, it's relatively simple in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Submersed. I have edited the question. Also, if ConstraintLayout is better, how would I get it so the advert was always at the bottom of the phone's screen, and then the webview filled the entire rest of the screen, even if the webpage was not big enough to fill the entire screen?

Comment: Also        android:layout_centerInParent="true" I think is for relative layout.